# WPF C# | Keep textbox's pasted text's font and size

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, textbox

When I paste some text into a textbox, I want the text to have the font that is in the clipboard.

For example, when I copy some text from word with a specific font and size and then I paste it into a textbox in my program, I want to keep the font and size that the copied text had.

Answer (score 0):

Use the RichTextBox. It works with rtf format

Comment: Okay, but how do I programatically change the text in C#?